# dplyr filter: multiple conditions in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame which contains all the conditions.

```
cond.df = data.frame(
  mpg = c(21,18.7,22.8),
  gear = c(4,3,2),
  carb = c(4,3,2)
)
```

So for my first output, I want a filtered data frame which is equivalent to

```
mtcars %>% filter(mpg == 21, gear == 4, carb = 4)
```

My desired output would be a list with `n` data frames.

```
list(mtcars %>% filter(mpg == 21, gear == 4, carb = 4),
 mtcars %>% filter(mpg == 18.7, gear == 3, carb = 3),
 mtcars %>% filter(mpg == 22.8, gear == 2, carb = 2))
```

Also, if possible I want a solution for an unknown number of columns from `cond.df`.

I am aware that if I only have one variable I can use `%in%`, e.g.

```
mtcars %>% filter(gear %in% c(3,4))
```

However, I have more than one variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to use an `inner_join` of `mtcars` on your `cond.df`. This way, it can match on arbitrarily many variables in `cond.df`.

I changed your conditions data frame a bit such that the second and third row actually match something.

```
library(dplyr)
cond.df = data.frame(
    mpg = c(21,18.7,22.8),
    gear = c(4,3,4),
    carb = c(4,2,1)
)
```

This creates a dataframe with the filtered/joined dataframes in each row.

```
result <- 
    cond.df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    do(
        dfs = inner_join(as.data.frame(.), mtcars)
    )
```

In case you need it as a list of dataframes, just convert it.

```
as.list(result)$dfs
```

Comment: Instead of `as.list(result)$dfs` you may want to run `do.call(rbind.data.frame, result$dfs)` to get the data back into a single data frame...

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply to go over your cond.df row-wise, and then use an anonymous function to filter:

```
apply(cond.df,1, function(x) mtcars %>% # the 1 is for row wise 
filter(mpg == x[1], gear == x[2], carb == x[3]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i should edit the question. I want a solution with unknown number of columns in `cond.df`